# Subprocess unable to run batch file to open jar

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
def createBat():
    fileSelected = "C:/Users/Haydomon/Desktop/folder/"
    Batch = open(fileSelected+"run.bat", 'w+')
    Batch.write('java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar paper-1.16.4')
    Batch.close()
    subprocess.Popen(fileSelected+"run.bat")
createBat()
```

"Error: Unable to access jarfile paper-1.16.4"

The bat file opens a minecraft server jar called "paper-1.16.4", The bat file works when clicked
manually.

Comment: can you tell me what OS you are using

Comment: he is obviously using windows..

Comment: Your batch file cannot fnd the `.jar` file. Put the full path in your command, or do a `pushd`/`popd` in the batch file.

Comment: can you change `fileSelected+"run.bat"` to `os.path.join(fileSelected, "run.bat")` and tell us if it helped? I believe your paths are wrong (don't forget to `import os`)

Comment: Sounds like your Java `CLASSPATH` is wrong. The batch file is completely redundant here; simply `subprocess.Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-Xms1024M', '-jar', 'paper-1.16.4')`